# How to isolate bluetooth device mfg and model when not listed in specs?

Tags: linux, windows-8, drivers, bluetooth

I am working on an HP Pavilion DV7-6166NR that has various potential matches from HP's driver section.  I have not been able to find any actual enumeration or specification of what Bluetooth device this laptop may have.  I was curious, what method would you recommend  to ascertain specific device information in order to isolate the correct drivers for such a scenario?

In linux I'd do something like `lspci` to dig about, but I'm not really sure what options are appropriate in this scenario with Windows 8.  Additionally, there is an "unknown device" listed in the Windows device manager and so I have to think that this is the bluetooth device since I don't see it enumerated anywhere else in the device manager.

Finally, one other point that I have seen mentioned before is about the device being turned off.  I cannot see any way that this device can be turned off on this laptop with any kind of physical or software based switch.